# jmap -histo with a specific object at Windows

Tags: java, windows, memory, java-8, jmap

While testing my jar application at Linux I use the command line below to track the usage/memory load of a specific object (eg JButton).

```
jmap -histo:live <pid> | grep JButton
```

Which results:

```
35:            24          11136  javax.swing.JButton
99:            31           2728  javax.swing.JButton$AccessibleJButton
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with Windows but I cannot find a similar command (like grep) to track a specific object. `jmap -histo[:live] <pid>` provides a full list of all objects. Does Windows have similar tools for such usage or an alternate way?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7

Comment: You can use [`find "JButton"`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx). Note that the quotes are required.

Comment: @Holger I just tested it and works just fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Eugene very useful link. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the suggestions from comments and we have an answer now:

```
jmap -histo:live <pid> | grep JButton
```

from **Linux** is equivalent to:

```
jmap -histo:live <pid> | find "JButton"
```

or

```
jmap -histo:live <pid> | findstr JButton
```

from **Windows**.